# How to reverse on two conditions under an apache reverse proxy

Tags: apache-2.4, reverse-proxy, httpd

I'm new on apache reverse proxy, and I trying to reverse Url calling like bellow:

[Principe-forwarding-schema.jpg](https://postimg.cc/nM7j3mPF)

I'm able to forward all request on Webserver1 like that:

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>  

 ProxyPreserveHost On  
 ServerName localhost  
 ProxyPass / http://webserver1/  
 ProxyPassReverse / http://webserver1/  
 </VirtualHost>
```

But I'm not able to make condition on Url Param example:

If "http://reverse.proxy.com/?param=foo" then forwarding it to WebServer 2

And also, I don't know if those rules could be on the Same configuration.

Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For conditionals like you describe you have to use mod_rewrite to proxy.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^param=foo$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://webserver2/$1 [P,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://webserver1/$1 [P,L]
```

Explanation:
First we check for the query string you want to match, if it matches the following RewriteRule is applied, but if it doesn't match the second RewriteRule will apply.